# yarn audit in a monorepo

Tags: yarnpkg, audit, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

We're using `yarn audit` extensively in our daily workflow, but we encountered an issue: in a monorepo that uses yarn workspaces `yarn audit` seems to scan *the entire repo*. Our current workaround is to run the audit, cache the result, and filter it by the path to actual service we're auditing - but this is slow and counterproductive. Is there a way to limit audit to actual service being audited?